# Windows 10 Norton.exe Trying to Access Controlled Folders

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, norton-antivirus, controlled-folder-access

I don't really know much about computers lol but this has been bothering me.

I turned on controlled folders a small while ago, just because I thought it was good to have on, and around the same time, I kept getting pop-ups of Norton Security Ultra saying my protection was "Deceased!," "Gone!," etc. I never paid mind to them, and exited them when they popped up.

Anyway, now I keep getting notifications from Windows Antivirus that Norton.exe is trying to access and/or make changes to controlled folders. I have never installed Norton or anything else, I've only used Windows Defender. I am just creeped out that Norton is trying to do these things, but I've never downloaded it. Also, I can't find anything Norton-related in my folders. (Don't know if it makes a difference, but Im on a laptop btw)

Is this something I should be worried about? Also, is there a way to make it stop if it is something to be concerned for? Thanks for your help :) I appreciate it

Comment: You can add specific applications to the list of safe or allowed processes, to access your controlled folders. Norton scans files even when not activated (then requires activation for actual removal). Norton recommends using their remover tool to uninstall, with instructions here: https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v15972972

Comment: So Cpt.Whale do you recommend I allow it to the folders, or uninstall? Again, I don't know much yet, but does Norton come installed already on the computer? Because I never installed it. Thanks for your comment! :)

Comment: Many applications like Norton often come pre-installed, depending on who the computer was purchased from. Whether you want to disable the folder protection, allow access, or just remove norton is up to you. Disabling protection is the easiest solution like John suggests

Comment: Haha, okay, thank you both very much!! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also, is there a way to make it stop?

I suggest turning off Controlled Folders (Windows Defender Security settings). I experimented with this on a Windows 11 machine (same setting) and it trapped normal software.

This is one thing not worth running because it causes issues where none exist.